# Can I pass an associative array as an argument to ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs?

Tags: php, reflection

Is it possible to pass parameters as an associative array in `ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs`? This would allow me to pass the arguments in a different order than declared.

For example:

```
class A
{
    public function someMethod($a, $b)
    {
        return sprintf("a - %s, b - %s", $a, $b);
    }
}

$rm = new ReflectionMethod('A', 'someMethod');
echo $rm->invokeArgs(new A(), array('b' => 1, 'a' => 2));
```

Comment: What happened when you tried? What does the documentation say? What research have you done so far?

Comment: Print 'a - 1, b - 2', but should 'a - 2, b - 1'

Comment: Then that's your answer, isn't it? What part of your analysis of those results did you need help with?

Comment: I want to pass parameters to a method in a different order, different from order in the description.

Comment: I want to print: 'a - 2, b - 1'

Comment: Yes, I know you do. You still haven't answered my question.

Comment: How can I transmit 'b' value in $b param and 'a' value in $a param?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by overwriting the `invokeArgs` method and implementing the functionality you need (in your case it looks like you want to use named arguments):

```
class ReflectionMethodA extends ReflectionMethod
{
    public function invokeArgs($object, Array $args = array())
    {
        $parameters = $this->getParameters();
        foreach($parameters as &$param) 
        {
            $name = $param->getName();
            $param = isset($args[$name]) ? $args[$name] : $param->getDefaultValue();
        }
        unset($param);

        return parent::invokeArgs($object, $parameters);
    }
}

$rm = new ReflectionMethodA('A', 'someMethod');

echo $rm->invokeArgs(new A(), array('b' => 1, 'a' => 2));
```

Output:

```
a - 2, b - 1
```

**Edit:** An improved (supporting both named and numbered arguments as well as passing by reference) and more flexible variant (to be used for any callback) is the following class, taking any valid callback as parameter in it's constructor.

Usage:

```
$rc = new ReflectedCallback(array(new A(), 'someMethod'));
echo $rc->invokeArgs(array('b' => 1, 'a' => 2));
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/1526670)

Comment: I think he's looking to map keys to the names of parameters; it may only just happen that `a` and `b` are lexicographically ordered in this case.

Comment: Well, edited, the way to do it is the same, just the implementation differs. `ksort` was more of a short example ;)

Comment: So solution will be actually good if it would still accept a numbered array as well. Right now it does not. Additionally it should be some sort of decorator so that it works for the various `invokeArgs` functions that are available.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's nothing in [the manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invokeargs.php) that suggests you can use an associative array to re-order arguments by name.

Comment: @hakre: Megalulz ;) Thanks for the thought, though